# aggregate value in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

i have data like this table

```
ItemId  Value   Date
1        2      2017-12-18 17:00:00.000
1        2      2017-12-18 17:02:00.000
1        2      2017-12-18 17:04:00.000
1        3      2017-12-18 17:06:00.000
1        3      2017-12-18 17:08:00.000
1        2      2017-12-20 17:10:00.000
1        2      2017-12-20 17:12:00.000
```

i want to output like this in sql server

```
ItemId     Value   MaxDate

1          2       2017-12-18 17:04:00.000
1          3       2017-12-18 17:08:00.000
1          2       2017-12-20 17:12:00.000
```

I'm sorry, I did not get a better sentence for my title

Comment: So you want the max date for each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a difference of row numbers approach. Look at the results of the inner query that classifies consectuive rows with the same value into one group which can be used to get the final result.

```
select itemid,value,max(date)
from (
select t.*,
row_number() over(partition by itemid order by date)
-row_number() over(partition by itemid,value order by date) as grp
from tbl t
) t
group by itemid,value,grp
```

Edit: Just getting the `min` or `max` would be easier with Gordon's answer. However, if both `min`, `max` and `sum` and other aggregations are needed per group, this version would be better.

Comment: dear Vamsi Prabhala i added a row ItemId = 1 , Value = 4 and Date = 2017-12-18 17:12:00.000
and I edited last  row  date 2017-12-18 17:12:00.000 to date 2017-12-18 17:14:00.000 
output  broked down can you help me about this change?

Comment: @HoseinMasoomi .. what do you mean by output break down?

Comment: the output was wrong with new data 
look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887679/how-to-difference-of-row-numbers-approach

Answer (score 1):

You want the rows where the next row has a different value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(value) over (partition by itemid order by date) as next_value
      from t
     ) t
where next_value is null or next_value <> value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are trying to do a basic aggregation where you want the max datetime value for each day or you are trying to do an islands and gaps problem where the group is defined because the "previous" row changes value. But I think you just need basic aggregation.

Here is a fully working example which return the output you stated you want.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ItemId int
    , Value int
    , [Date] datetime
)
insert @Something values
(1, 2, '2017-12-18 17:00:00.000')
, (1, 2, '2017-12-18 17:02:00.000')
, (1, 2, '2017-12-18 17:04:00.000')
, (1, 3, '2017-12-18 17:06:00.000')
, (1, 3, '2017-12-18 17:08:00.000')
, (1, 2, '2017-12-20 17:10:00.000')
, (1, 2, '2017-12-20 17:12:00.000')

select ItemId
    , Value
    , MaxDate = Max([Date])
from @Something
group by ItemId
    , Value
    , convert(Date, [Date])
order by MAX([Date])
```