# how to difference of row numbers approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

i have data like this table

```
ItemId  Value   Date
1        2      2017-12-18 17:00:00.000
1        2      2017-12-18 17:02:00.000
1        2      2017-12-18 17:04:00.000
1        3      2017-12-18 17:06:00.000
1        3      2017-12-18 17:08:00.000
1        2      2017-12-18 17:10:00.000
1        2      2017-12-18 17:12:00.000
1        2      2017-12-18 17:16:00.000
1        4      2017-12-18 17:14:00.000
```

i want to output like this in sql server

```
ItemId     Value   MaxDate
1          2       2017-12-18 17:04:00.000
1          3       2017-12-18 17:08:00.000
1          2       2017-12-18 17:16:00.000
1          4       2017-12-18 17:14:00.000
```

thanks for your anwsers.

Comment: What's the logic for your output?

Comment: I think the last row of your sample data is wrong?

Comment: why tupla itemid,value(1,2) has two max date? And where Value 4 comes from?

Comment: I edited my question MiloBellano

Comment: @HoseinMasoomi - Why is the row `1,4,'2017-12-18 17:14:00.000'` at the end?  It's date is 2minutes  Earlier than the row Before it...

Comment: Looks a lot like the one you asked yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872427/aggregate-value-in-different-rows

Comment: @MatBailie That's because the value is 4 and befor it is 2 and these are different for me

Comment: @SeanLange : yes i asked, but my data table changed and the output was wrong

Comment: @hoseinmasoomi - you say "before it is 2", but the fire "before" has a time that is "after". Look at the times you've given; the last row in your sample data goes backwards in time by two minutes compared to the preceding row.  Why are the rows not sorted by time?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want the last row before `value` changes, although I'm not sure where value "4" comes from (my best guess is that the last input row should have a "4" and a different timestamp).

If so, you can simply use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(value) over (partition by itemId order by date) as next_value
      from t
     ) t
where next_value is null or next_value <> value;
```

Comment: That value `4` could be very important.  Because the last two rows of the sample data are not in timestamp order, and so the results aren't in timestamp order either.  Until it is clarified, it is possible that this is not solvable without an additional field to enforce relative order.